How can I hide token in my .json file on github
I have an identity.json file. in which I have added a token. so I directly added a token in my file and pushed to github. now when my token is visible in github. and I don't want it to be visible. Is there any way I can hide this token?
person.json file
{
    "admin_token": "J0eXAiOi676767676767676767676767WNjZXNzX2xlds",
    "version": "Unknown",
    "id": "37e9e-4108-ad1e-97e009f700"
}

I am working on a flutter project. this file is part of my project-2. my project-1 is depends on project-2. my other project is using this file. that's why I put my token like this.
my project-1 pubspec.yaml file
dependencies:
  project-2:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:project-2.git
      ref: master

I do not want my admin_token to be visible like this on Git Hub.
Is there anything that I can do using a variable in person.json file like the one below and store the value of $ADMIN_TOKEN in GitHub somewhere? so on GitHub, it is visible as a variable.
{
    "admin_token": "$ADMIN_TOKEN",
    "version": "Unknown",
    "id": "37e9e-4108-ad1e-97e009f700"
}


Usually, you should never put secret information into your repository

you can create .gitignore file in your root directory and add file name that should not be tracked and not to upload to your github repo.
